# How to reduce the width of button and put it in center

Tags: flutter

I have just started learning flutter, I have a screen that contains a form, I'd like to know how to reduce the width of button and put it in center.

[image]

This the code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Ajouter note'),
    centerTitle: true,
    backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
  ),
  body: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    child: Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Saisir un titre',
            ),
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            minLines: 10,
            maxLines: 10,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Saisir une déscription',
            ),
            // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
          RaisedButton.icon(
            onPressed: () {
              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')));
              }
            },
            label: Text(
              'Enregistrer',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.save,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            color: Colors.pink,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be wrapping the `RaisedButton` in a `Padding`.

You can apply padding only horizontal axis.

```
Padding(
   padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
   child: // your RaisedButton
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways of doing it. One option is to limit the size of your button like this:

```
 Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 100,
        child: RaisedButton(
          ...
         ),
      ),
    )
```